# Android Json Parsing from html with Volley no value found

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I'm trying to parse a json html in my project with Volley. Json look like this:
[image]

And here is my code block:

```
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("channels");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject channel = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String song = channel.getString("song");
                        String artist = channel.getString("age");
                        int duration = channel.getInt("duration");
                        double playedat = channel.getDouble("playedat");
                        String img = channel.getString("image_extralarge");

                        System.out.println(song + ", " + String.valueOf(duration) + ", " + img + "\n\n");
                    }
```

but whenever I run my code I get nothing with following errors:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for channels
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:587)
        at com.example.korhan.frontend.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:71)
        at com.example.korhan.frontend.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:67)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
```

Comment: It looks like your elements aren't in an array.  That's why the conversion to `JSONArray` isn't working.

Comment: Do you know how can parse them? @AnxGotta

Comment: I posted a possible solution for you below @K. Keser

Answer (score 1):

Because your response isn't a `JSONArray`, you'll have to convert your response into a `JSONObject` and then reference each sub-object by name.

What I would suggest for you is to iterate through and do what you want with the values:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    Iterator<String> iterator = response.keys();

    while (iterator.hasNext() {
        String channelName = iterator.next().toString();
        JSONObject channelObject = new JSONObject(response.get(channelName).toString()));
        String song = channelObject.getString("song");
        /// do other things... getString, getInt
    }
}
```

Check here for more `get` methods =>
[JSONObject Methods](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/data/JSONObject.html)

Comment: If the solution worked for you, remember to mark it accepted so it's understood to be closed.